# Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 tearing with intel j1900

Tags: gnome, intel-graphics, tearing

I just bought a Mini-ITX motherboard with **j1900** CPU to use as a HTPC.
It has a Intel graphics but i get tearing and i cant find any settings for Vsync or or video acceleration.

The tearing does not occur in Lubuntu, only in unity and gnome and i really want to use gnome as my desktop environment.

Tearing occurs in Kodi and Youtube.

***What i have tried:***

```
Vsync allways on in kodi
Changing FPS to match the video
Update intel graphic drivers
```